# Error while performing ionic platform add android command in ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have installed nvm, and then perform following commands respectively as mentioned on [ionic website](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
ionic start myApp tabs
```

and finally

```
cd myApp
ionic platform add ios
```

I have not used sudo(root user) while installing above commands in Ubuntu 16.04
I am getting following errors.

```
Error: Failed to fetch platform android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, utime '/home/dell/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/5.2.2/package/.npmignore'
```

Comment: I think you will have to use to use sudo, I had the same issue not so long ago and the issue was resolved with it.

Comment: Issue solved by removing and installing node, cordova and ionic as mentioned on ionic website and setting up android paths in ~/.bashrc